# Why are buttons making my canvas drawing like hexagon shape in Android?

Tags: android, xml

[image: Smooth circle]  [image]I have a strange problem I'm creating a canvas drawing app in Android that has lots of buttons in xml file.  The problems is  when I draw a circle with all those buttons included in the file it's never a smooth circle it's full of corners like hexagon shape but when I exclude buttons may be leaving in one or two, it draws a perfect smooth circle. I have tried to split the file into three so I've included them using  but still same result. Can someone please enlighten me what am I do wrong.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<!--First Draw -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/nav_one"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="100dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_tab_res_bkg"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/nav_two"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_tab_tools_bkg"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   <!-- The navigation drawer -->

   <ListView android:id="@+id/resource_bank"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/background_light"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#f4f1f1"
        />
    <ListView android:id="@+id/tools"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/background_light"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#dedada"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

    <xxxxx.xxxxxx.xxxx.xxxxxx.DrawView
        android:id="@+id/canvas_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <FrameLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/canvas_view">

        <!-- Pen icons -->

    <include  layout="@layout/activity_pen_color" android:id="@+id/pen_color" />
    <include layout="@layout/activity_pen_style"  android:id="@+id/pen_style" />

        <!--  Navigation bar icons  -->

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:background="@drawable/icon_bar_bkg"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ic_select"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:elevation="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_select_bkg"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_select"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="150dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
            android:text="Select"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ic_pens"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
            android:elevation="1dp"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_pen_bkg"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_pens"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
            android:text="Pen"
            android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
  </RelativeLayout>
```

My DrawView

```
public class DrawView extends View {

private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
private Canvas drawCanvas;
private Bitmap canvasBitmap;

private SparseArray<Path> paths;

public DrawView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    setupDrawing();
}

public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setupDrawing();
}

public DrawView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    setupDrawing();
}

private void setupDrawing() {
    paths = new SparseArray<>();

    drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(9);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    for (int i=0; i<paths.size(); i++) {
        canvas.drawPath(paths.valueAt(i), drawPaint);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    int index = event.getActionIndex();
    int id = event.getPointerId(index);

    Path path;
    switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
            path = new Path();
            path.moveTo(event.getX(index), event.getY(index));
            paths.put(id, path);
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            for (int i=0; i<event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
                id = event.getPointerId(i);
                path = paths.get(id);
                if (path != null) path.lineTo(event.getX(i), event.getY(i));
            }
            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
            path = paths.get(id);
            if (path != null) {
                drawCanvas.drawPath(path, drawPaint);
                paths.remove(id);
            }
            break;
        default:
            return false;
    }
    invalidate();
    return true;
}

/**
 * change path color here
 */
public void setPathColor(int color) {
    drawPaint.setColor(color);
 }
}
```

Comment: can you add a screen shot ?

Comment: I have just added two screenshots, just to show what happens when I include Buttons in XML file. I want the smooth circle with Buttons included in the file and that's the goal.

Comment: What code are you using to draw the circle?

Comment: I've just updated my code.

Comment: Tip: use `@greeble31` when you comment so I get a notification in my inbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer**

I take it that you are drawing this circle with your finger, and that when a lot of extra buttons are present, you notice that the lines you draw with your finger become "less smooth".

This is related to the app's screen refresh rate. When your app has to spend lots of time drawing all those extra buttons, it has fewer opportunities to get `MotionEvents`. With fewer `MotionEvents`, there are fewer points in your shape, and it takes longer line segments to connect them.

**Suggested fix**

The recommended approach is to stop those button views from being invalidated (an assumption on my part) every time `onTouchEvent()` gets called. From your code, I can't immediately see why they would be invalidated, but it may be that your DrawView *underlies* the buttons you are adding, thus whenever the DrawView is `invalidate()`-ed, the system must re-compose it with the buttons. You could move the DrawView so that it's by itself. Adding an opaque background to your button container(s) may help as well, b/c the system would have to do fewer alpha calculations.

You must have a lot of buttons... you may want to do some performance profiling to determine exactly what's taking so long.

Comment: Thank you, your answer makes lot of sense, let me work on your suggestions before I accept as an answer.